# Providing useful error on failed Avro Validation

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform

I have a python REST service that receives requests that contain an Avro schema definition and a payload.  The service needs to validate that the payload matches the provided schema.  If it is valid, it writes the message to a Kafka topic.  If it is not valid, it returns an error message.

I am using the avro.io.validate method to determine if the payload is valid.  That works, but it does not provide me with a useful error message.  The best that I have figured out is to return the payload and the schema and tell the caller that the data is not valid.  I would like to provide them with a more useful error message.

Most of the Avro/Kafka work in the application is using Confluent Kafka libraries, but I could not find a good way to validate with them.  If there is something I missed in the Confluent libraries, I am game to try that, otherwise I feel that I am stuck using the avro.io validate method, or roll my own.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: If you cannot parse the payload using the schema, then it is invalid, right?

Comment: Can you give an example of the schema and data you are using that produces the error message that is not sufficient?

Comment: the avro.io.validate simply returns true or false.  There is no message from validate.  It is my API that needs to return a message.  The only information that I have at hand is the event, the schema, and a True/False.  I want to provide more guidance than "bad data"

Comment: You could try using the fastavro validation: https://fastavro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/validation.html. If it isn't useful then please leave an issue on the github repo and it can probably be made better.